# What is a memoryless nonlinear boolean function?

Tags: terminology, discrete-mathematics, cryptography, coding-theory

I have been reading about shift register based keystream generators in cryptography. One usual method of generating keystream sequences is feeding the output of several Linear Feedback Shift Registers to a "memoryless nonlinear Boolean fuction". I googled around about memoryless functions but I haven't found much about *Boolean* ones.

Can somebody explain what a memoryless boolean function is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this term was in the context of the particular textbook. In fact, in the next section a keystream generator is introduced, where the output of the Linear Feedback Shift Register is fed to a Boolean function but there is also a "memory function" that saves (part of) the previous LFSR state. This previous LFSR state is also fed to the Boolean function. Then this boolean function is called a "Boolean function with memory". When we have a keystream generation where a memory function does not exist, then we have a "memoryless" Boolean function.